# import is not working nodeJs application React SSR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, import, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to implement SSR for a React application I started with creating a server directory that contains 3 files (bootstrap, index, renderer)

bootstrap.js contains babel configs to transpile to es5

index.js create an express application and express Router

renderer.js is responsible for rendering React application to string and send it as html to client.

bootstap.js =>

```
require('ignore-styles');

require('@babel/register')({
  ignore: [
    function (filePath) {
      return !filePath.includes('node_modules');
    }
  ],
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/flow'
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "react-loadable/babel",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "dynamic-import-node"
  ]
});

require('./index');
```

index.js =>

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';


dotenv.config();

const express = require('express');
const serverRenderer = require('./middleware/renderer');


const PORT = process.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 3000 : 7160;
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
const router = express.Router();
const routes = require('../src/router/appRoutes').default;


router.use(express.static(
  path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
  { maxAge: '30d' },
));


routes.map(path => app.get(path, serverRenderer));

app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', error);
  }

  console.log("listening on " + PORT + "...");
});
```

but when I run

```
NODE_ENV=production node server/bootstrap.js
```

this command to start server side application I get this error

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
       ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Module._compile (/Users/amirtahani/projects/uneed/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/amirtahani/projects/uneed/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/amirtahani/projects/uneed/server/bootstrap.js:34:1)
```

and the weird thing is the same code is working on another project.
and here is my devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.6.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.6.3",
    "@babel/register": "7.6.2",
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.26.2",
    "flow-bin": "0.102.0",
    "ignore-styles": "5.0.1"
  }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Hi Amir, please are you found solution for your issues ?

Answer (score 1):

"import --from --" is ES15 syntax, however node.js uses commonJS module syntax. So you need to install and configure webpack. Babel just trans-piles the new generation javascript into the old javascript code. However webpack is going to bundle your application code into a single file and your server file will be executed through that bundle.js.

For server-side rendering you need 2 bundle.js. one for client and another one for server. HTML files without javascript have no functionality.

if we start from server, this is how we write our code into the index.js.

```
const renderToString=require("react-dom/server").renderToString //specifically created for server
const  Home=require("./components/Home").default //home component
const React=require("react")
const express=require("express")
const app=express()
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
const content =renderToString(<Home/>)
res.send(content)
})
```

This is how we render our code to the browser for "/" route. there are 2 flaws here. First one, we are sending file without javascript code. Any functionality in Home component will not work. For example, if you had button inside Home component with click event, that click event will not work. Because server is not shipping down any javascript code. Second flaw is we used jsx here:

`const content =renderToString(<Home/>).` so when node executes this file, it will not recognize this syntax and will give error.

to fix those 2 issues, we need webpack. webpack will transform index.js into a file which we specify the name and its location. In server-side, we usually name the file bundle.js inside public folder. So when we start the server with node or nodemon, we will execute public/bundle.js NOT the index.js file.

So we need to reorganize the code inside index.js and this time since webpack will transform the code, we can use "import" syntax.

```
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import Home from "./components/Home"
import React from "react"
import express from "express";

const app=express()
app.use(express.static("public")) //This will make public folder publicly available so we can ship it down to the browser. 

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
const content=renderToString(<Home/>)
//I used template strings ``
const html= `
  <html> 
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <div  id="root">${content}</div>
  <script src="bundle.js"> </script>
//since we are sending a file, express will look for bundle.js inside the public folder. So we do not need to write relative path or absolute path.
  </body></html> `
res.send(html)
})
```

Now we need a file to configure webpack. We name it webpack.config.js in the root of the app.

```
const path=require("path")
module.exports={
//in server side we keep client and server logic inside src folder
entry:"./src/index.js", //relative path
mode:"development",
output:{filename:bundle.js,
       path:path.resolve(__dirname,"build")},
//absolute path. that is why we use native node module path. also you do not need to create build folder. webpack will create automatically
module:{rules:[{test:/\.js$/,
                loader:"babel-loader",
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                options:{presets:["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]}}]}

}
```

lastly in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev:server": "nodemon  --watch build --exec \"node build/bundle.js\"",
    "dev:build-server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch",
    "dev:build-client": "webpack --config webpack.client.js --watch"
  },
```

in dev:server we watch "build" folder for changes.(build folder is in the root of app.) then we execute "bundle.js" file inside the build directory.

so to give an answer to your question, this is the basic of server-side part of isomorphic javascript app.

Answer (score 0):

I installed node LTS (v12.13.0) but got the same error when used `import` instead of `require`. It seems that `es6 imports` are still an experimental feature, even in the latest node version.

If you want to test this feature, you need to do these steps:

1. Add `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`
2. Run your server with this flag: `--experimental-modules`. e.g. `NODE_ENV=production node --experimental-modules server/bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 0):

`import` and `export` syntax is still experimental in node js latest versions, but there is a work around to this issue.

try to add `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` file and change your `.js` bundle extension to `.mjs` in your webpack config and run your generated file with this command:

```
NODE_ENV=production node --experimental-modules server/bootstrap.mjs
```

also i recommend you to read [this](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) page.

Answer (score -2):

First check if the dotenv package is installed or not. If not, you can install it in the following command -

> npm i --save dotenv

In order to use dotenv, you don't need to import it and then configure it.
Instead use the following syntax -

> require('dotenv').config()

Comment: the problem is with babel not understanding the import and export not with syntax if i use require instead of import the error will be with next import